# Format Output To Look Nice

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api

I receive output from Google API QPX Express.

[image: The output example]

How do I format them so that they can look more organized?

Thanks for any kind reply.

```
// Aircraft
foreach (var aircraft in result.Trips.Data.Aircraft)
{
    Response.Output.Write(aircraft.Name + aircraft.Code);
}

// Airport
foreach (var airport in result.Trips.Data.Airport)
{
    Response.Output.Write(airport.Name + " - " + airport.City);
}

foreach (var carrier in result.Trips.Data.Carrier)
{
    Response.Output.Write(carrier.Name);
}

foreach (var trip in result.Trips.TripOption)
{
    Response.Output.Write("Flight Number: " + trip.Slice.FirstOrDefault().Segment.FirstOrDefault().Flight.Number);
    Response.Output.Write("    Duration: " + trip.Slice.FirstOrDefault().Duration);
    Response.Output.Write("     Cabin: " + trip.Slice.FirstOrDefault().Segment.FirstOrDefault().Cabin);
    Response.Output.Write("   Price: " + trip.Pricing.FirstOrDefault().BaseFareTotal.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Please explain what do you mean 'look more organized'!

Comment: For my "Look more organized" is like putting it into a label or textbox and the result can appear in label or textbox one by one. Thanks for reply. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
    // Aircraft
    Response.Output.Write("<h3>Aircrafts</h3>");
    Response.Output.Write("<ul>");

    foreach (var aircraft in result.Trips.Data.Aircraft)
    {
        Response.Output.Write("<li>" + aircraft.Name + " " + aircraft.Code + "</li>");
    }

    Response.Output.Write("</ul>");
```

which would give something like

```html
<h3>Aircrafts</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Airbus 123456</li>
  <li>Airbus 123456</li>
  <li>Airbus 123456</li>
  <li>Airbus 123456</li>
</ul>
```

*Updated based on comment*

Or like this using `Label1.Text`

```
    // Aircraft
    foreach (var aircraft in result.Trips.Data.Aircraft)
    {
        Label1.Text += aircraft.Name + aircraft.Code;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. LGSon. Thanks for your reply. It is possible to output them into a textbox or label? I have tried lblOP.Text = "Result" for example, it only show me the last result which is price.

Comment: @CAP2100APR2016 If you post that non working code, I might be able to help

Comment: I just replace all 'Response.Output.Write' to 'Label1.Text'. I have uploaded the code as picture since here can't support too much comment. Please refer here. [url=http://www.pixhost.org/show/113/33376105_codepartone.png][img]http://t8.pixhost.org/thumbs/113/33376105_codepartone.png[/img][/url] [url=http://www.pixhost.org/show/113/33376106_codeparttwo.png][img]http://t8.pixhost.org/thumbs/113/33376106_codeparttwo.png[/img][/url] The result. [url=http://www.pixhost.org/show/113/33376107_codepartthree.png][img]http://t8.pixhost.org/thumbs/113/33376107_codepartthree.png[/img][/url]

Comment: Actually I just change 'Response.Output.Write' to 'Label1.Text'. I can't put my code here since it is so long. I uploaded as picture. [link]http://www.pixhost.org/show/113/33376105_codepartone.png [link]http://www.pixhost.org/show/113/33376106_codeparttwo.png
The outcome. [link]http://www.pixhost.org/show/113/33376107_codepartthree.png
Many much thanks if you can help me.

Comment: Please ignore the last second comment. The last comment will be better.

Comment: @CAP2100APR2016 You need to do like this `Label1.Text += aircraft.Name + aircraft.Code`, (note the `+=`) so you add the text, or else it overwrites the first assigned with the second and so on

Comment: @CAP2100APR2016 Updated my answer with a 2:nd sample

Comment: Hi. LGSon. Thanks a lot for you spending time helping me. Really thanks. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://datatables.net/ to format the output into a table.

Comment: Hi. KaNa. Thanks for your reply. I will have a try on it.